# Cache an intermediate variable in an one-liner

Tags: scala

Can I somehow cache the `i.toString` in this simple definition of function?

```
def palindrome(i: Int) = i.toString == i.toString.reverse
```

I want to keep this function simple, w/o a classic multi-line, brace-enclosed function..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
def palindrome(i: Int) = ((s:String) => s == s.reverse)(i.toString)
```

Comment: This is basically the same as PipedObject except PipedObject is reusable.

Answer (score 6):

Well, Scala doesn't have a let statement like some traditional functional languages, but that's largely because val + braces fulfill the same purpose. Are you objecting to the multi-line part or to braces in general? Because it's pretty hard to beat:

```
def palindrome(i: Int) = { val s = i.toString; s == s.reverse }
```

Attempts to elide the braces will likely only drive the character count up.

Comment: This is an obvious solution and I guess in real-world problems I'd use it. But while I'm learning Scala, I want something more interesting.. beause as you can see, in Scala even such a simple operation like the one in my question can be solved in 1000 ways .. while in Java (or x, y, z ) the answer is probably "*nah, you can only ... *" . Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Parobay I believe in nearly every programming language there are multiple ways to solve a problem

Answer (score 5):

Use the forward pipe operator:

```
scala> implicit class PipedObject[A](value: A) {
     |   def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(value)
     | }
defined class PipedObject

scala> def palindrome(i: Int) = i.toString |> (s => s == s.reverse)
palindrome: (i: Int)Boolean
```

While this solves your problem elegantly I advise to change the signature of `palindrome` from `palindrome(Int)` to `palindrome(String)` and call it with `palindrome(i.toString)` (and rename it to `isPalindrome`).

Comment: this is nice, but requires a second definition

Answer (score 3):

It is a one-liner, but the braces are still here. It seems shorter to me, though:

```
def palindrome(i: Int) = { val s = i.toString; s == s.reverse }
```

If you have many such functions, you could also do something like this:

```
@inline def let[T, R](expr: =>T)(body: T => R): R = body(expr)

def palindrome(i: Int) = let(i.toString) { s => s == s.reverse }
```

Comment: though this requires a second definition, I think the 2nd definition is the most universal. Nice solution +1 !

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library provides the chaining operation [`pipe`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B) which can be used to convert/pipe `i.toString` with the function checking if a string is a palindrome:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

def palindrome(i: Int) = i.toString.pipe(s => s == s.reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Needing to refer to something exactly twice comes up often enough that it's useful to have enrich it into a method:

```
implicit class DiamondMapper[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def diamond[B](f: (A,A) => B) = f(a,a)
}
```

Then:

```
scala> 575.toString.diamond(_ == _.reverse)
res1: Boolean = true
```

This is a special case of the pipe operator (`|>` if you like symbolic notation), but it's a common enough use case that you might want to create your own.

(Diamond here because it takes one value, splits it in two, and merges it back together again.)

Comment: this is nice, but requires a second definition